# Page or Form Not showing validation Error Django

Tags: python, django

Hello Guys I'm trying to show validation errors on Django forms. I do not know what's going on. I want to make a validation error if the username already exists in the database, but it ain't throwing me an error. Here is My code. In terminal its show the error but not in the page.

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.forms import fields
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput
User = get_user_model()

unallowed_username = ['hello']

class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username= forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "login-password form-control",
                "id": "login-password"
            }
        )
    )

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    username = forms.CharField()
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label="Password",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(

            attrs = {
                "class": "form-control user-password1",
                "id": "user-password"
            }
        )
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label="Confirm Password",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs = {
                "class": "form-control user-password2",
                "id": "user-confirm-password"
            }
        )
    )
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["first_name", "last_name","username", "email", "password1","password2"]

    
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        qs = User.objects.filter(username__iexact = username)
        if username in unallowed_username:

            raise forms.ValidationError("This username is unproper Username Please pick another")
        if qs.exists():
            print("invalid username")
            raise forms.ValidationError(("This is an Invalid Username Please pick another"))
    
        
        return username

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        qs = User.objects.filter(email__iexact = email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This email is already in use.")
        return email

    def clean_password(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data["password1"]
        password2 = self.cleaned_data["password2"]
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password 1 and Password 2 Don't match")
        
        return password1
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm
# Create your views here.
def register_view(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

Index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
   
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#try below view

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm
# Create your views here.
def register_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            #please write redirect here otherwise gives error
        else: 
            context = {"form":form}
            return render(request, "index.html", context)
            
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```